# Is it possible to view int as decimal AND hexadecimal at the same time in intellij?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

When debugging in intellij, I can tell it to display a given int variable with its decimal value or its hex value.

Is it possible for the debugger to display BOTH at the same time?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am writing (well, trying) a 6502 emulator, and it would be very handy to see the hexadecimal and its correspondent decimal value, particularly for registers.

Comment: or be able to select a global setting and have it stay put, Or set it for a field and have it stay put.  The reasn is I have a breakpoint and a message comes in and I need to view a particular field ( or just all of them ) in hex each time the break point gets hit.  It really slows down the work if I have to right click, select item, each time instead of repeatedly hitting F9  the really NASTY workaround it to put a String test = Double.toHextString(myField) in the method and that displays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

When debugging, you can right click on an integer variable and choose `View As >` and either `Hex` or `Primitive`, not both.

This setting only applies to the single variable and doesn't seem to persist through different debugging sessions.

I had a look at the possibility of using a *Data Type Renderer* (right click a variable and go in to `Customize Data Views...` to see the dialog).

A Data Type Renderer only applies to complex data types (not primitives). So if for example your `int` that you wanted to see `38` and `0x26` was always part of a complex object (e.g. `Person.age`) then perhaps a data type renderer could help.

Alternatively you could add a String watch expression that constructs a String value for both the decimal and hex value of your int.

Sorry that there is not a way to do exactly what you want but I hope these 2 other suggestions are useful to consider.

Comment: Actually the idea of adding a string watch expression will do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible, at least in Android Studio 2.1 which is built on intellij.
Open Settings -> Built... -> Debugger -> Data views -> Java and enable *Show hex value for primitives*. Then it shows integer and hex in braces in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from IDEA 2016.3 it's possible to define custom Java Type Renderers for primitive types (including arrays): https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2016-3

With this feature you can display your primitive value any way you like.